# Possible to discard return character when using std::cin >>?

Tags: c++

When using the >> operator in c++ to capture user input, is it possible to prevent the console from printing the newline that is generated when the user presses the return key?

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you mean? In what case is the new line printed?

Comment: I don't think you can prevent it but you can deal with it by moving the cursor.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209370/how-do-i-input-variables-using-cin-without-creating-a-new-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot prevent `newline` character, because when you use `cin`, you are communicating with `system core`, which is not under control by users. `console` will return, when you enter `\n` or `EOF` or other exception situation.
So the better way is to use `getchar()` to capture the '\n', and do not leave it in `buffer`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to prevent this newline behavior by inputting two EOFs instead of Carriage Return from the keyboard. After entering your string at the console prompt, hit

> CTRL-D, CTRL-D

Note, this is a platform specific answer. This works on my Mac, but on Windows OS the EOF sequence may be CTRL-Z, RETURN. I would appreciate an answer edit <-- HERE.

Alternately, you can ditch the >> operator and use something like std::getline and specify an exact string termination delimiter. For example:

```
std::string myString;
std::getline(std::cin, myString, ';');
std::cout << myString;
```

This will read from standard input to `myString`, and put the string terminating NULL character where it finds the first semicolon `';'`. Then you'll only have to hit CTRL-D (input EOF) once.

Answer (score 0):

You can enter the values or input by pressing space every time. But at the end you must press enter key.
Let's say: you want to enter "5,4,3,2,1"
You can do:  `5 [enter] 4 [enter] 3[enter] 2[enter] 1[enter]`
Also: `5[space]4[space]3[space]2[space]1[enter]`
But if you want to print the output near input, you can simply print the input first and than you can print the what you want.
Example:
Input: `3` Output: `input+1`
So you will do:

```
cout<<input;
cout<<" "<<input+1<<endl;
```

Good luck :)