# Cin>> multiple times on the same line

Tags: c++, arrays, cin

I want to use `cin>>` in c++ to write the values into a bi-dimensional array on the same line..I don't know English very well but I'll show you an example:

So I have an array and I want to write in it 24 numbers(4 rows, 6 colons) and I want to input all the 6 numbers on the same line not like `cin>>` usually does like jumping on a new line.
I got this so far :

```
int m,n,i,j,a[50][50];
    cout<<"Input the number of rows : ";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"Input the number of columns : ";
    cin>>m;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            cout<<"Introduceti a["<<i+1<<"]["<<j+1<<"] : ";
            cin>>a[i][j];
        }
    }
```

But this does the usual jump on a new line every time I input something.

Is that possible?..Thank you! :)

Thank you!  :)

Comment: You can't do this with cin alone; see some of the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209370/how-do-i-input-variables-using-cin-without-creating-a-new-line

Comment: Why don't use use ```std::getline()``` to get the entire line, then tokenize it, and use the tokens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with `cin >> value` which usually requires the User to press ENTER to cause the processing of the input.

The ENTER is echoed back, causing a new blank line.

As others have said, you could use `std::getline()` to read a lot of data before the ENTER is pressed.

The question is, is a blank line echoed really worth the effort to avoid?