# How can i Keep "Enter" in the current line when receiving information from the user in the console by c++?

Tags: c++, console-application, clr

```
int Plus(){
int a = 0, b = 0;
cin >> a;
cout << "\b + ";
cin >> b;
cout<<" = "<<a + b;
return a+b;}
```

I want the result to be printed on the console in one line like this: 
1+2=3

Answer (score 0):

Don't use return like this! I would suggest an easy solution for you. Three variables. Just add a `c` variable where you will keep the result. And:

`cout << a <<"+" <<b << "=" << c <<endl;`

//I see you have named the function "Plus" so i believe you use it only this way. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

well you cannot keep "Enter" in same line if you use cin.

better way to do this is by using

```
#include<conio.h>
```

and _getchar()

the question is already been answered here:

[How do I input variables using cin without creating a new line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209370/how-do-i-input-variables-using-cin-without-creating-a-new-line)

Still, if you want to keep using cin, try something like this:

```
cin>>a>>b;
cout<<a<<" + "<<b<<" = "<<a+b;
```