# How to enter a value in C++ without pressing ENTER?

Tags: c++

I'm working on a C++ game project. I want to set the movements of my character with the <kbd>W</kbd>,<kbd>D</kbd>,<kbd>A</kbd> keys, but when I get them as input from the user with `std::cin`, I have to press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to verify. I do not want it to happen that way. I just want to press the keys and movements will happen. What is your idea for that??

```cpp
char input;

std::cin>>input ;

if(input==w)
    ...
else if(input==d)
    ...
else if(input==a)
    ...
```

Comment: Standard `c++` does not have this. You can use a library or possibly an OS API.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209370/how-do-i-input-variables-using-cin-without-creating-a-new-line

Comment: You might find this useful : [ncurses](https://jbwyatt.com/ncurses.html)

Comment: C++ supports a very large umbrella of systems and many of them don't have or support keyboards. Since C++ has to work the same on all of these systems, C++ does not acknowledge the existence of keyboards, pixels, and networks, though formal Standard-approved support for networks will likely be coming soon as a few remaining sticking points are hammed out.